# Ajax polling in Coffeescript - whats falling out of scope and why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, polling

I'd like to reload an iframe when the images needed to generate the preview it will display are cached by background workers (which can take a little while.)

```
class Preview
  constructor: (preview) ->
    @preview = preview
    @loadWhenCachedPoll() unless @preview.data?.footprintsCached?

  loadWhenCachedPoll: ->
    @interval = null
    @interval = setInterval(@loadWhenCached(), 3000)

  loadWhenCached: ->
    console.log "polling"
    $.ajax(
      url: "/user_image_caches/cached",
      method: "GET"
      dataType: "JSON"
      success: (data) =>
        if data["cached"] == "true"
          clearInterval(@interval)
          @preview.data.footprintsCached.val("true")
          @preview.attr('src', '/certificate.pdf')
    )

jQuery ->
  new Preview $("[data-behavior='preview']")
```

It runs successfully the first time, then every time after that I get
`Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

signaling that something fell out of scope.

Comment: Where do you get the error? That has nothing to do with scope; it probably means that your server is returning invalid JSON.

Comment: Hmm. Jumped in to monitor the server, and it looks like its serving up json fine. And that error message points to something in javascript land

Comment: What is "something in javascript land"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two errors:

1. You're calling `setInterval` with `loadWhenCached`'s return value instead of the `loadWhenCached` function itself.
2. `loadWhenCached` is not bound to anything so `this` won't be what you expect it to be when `setInterval` calls it.

The first one is easy to fix, pass the function reference rather than calling the function:

```
setInterval(@loadWhenCached, 3000) # No function-calling parentheses
```

Your version is calling `loadWhenCached` while the argument list for `setInterval` is being built rather than being called by `setInterval`.

The second can be fixed in various ways. You can make `loadWhenCached` a bound method using a [fat-arrow](http://coffeescript.org/#fat-arrow):

```
loadWhenCached: =>
  #...
```

or you could bind it using [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) when calling `setInterval`:

```
setInterval(@loadWhenCached.bind(@), 3000)
```

Comment: by the gods! I never realized the distinction between the function reference, and invoking the function itself. This all makes sense now! mu is too short, thanks for taking the time to type out your answer - I deeply appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

My rough guess would be that you're losing your "this" binding in the setInterval, since setInterval occurs on the window.  I'd throw a console.log to check the 'this', or bind/wrap the @loadWhenCached() in an anonymous function inside the setInterval.  I haven't worked with coffeescript in awhile though, so maybe the '@' accounts for this.